# How to decrease size of array by shifting elements to left after removing an element in first index?

Tags: c

I'm a bit confused on how to accomplish this task.

Let's say I define an array with size 5

```
int array[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
```

Then I remove an element in the first index, i.e. 1

How do I shift the elements to the left, and shrink the size by 1 to accomplish this?

```
int array[] = {2, 3, 4, 5};
```

Now the array size should be 4, i.e. I dont want the last index 4 to still contain 5, I would like the last index to be deleted so that the size of the array is 4

I have this code and went in reverse order but I dont think it's right:

```
for (int i = sizeof(array) - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
   array[i-1] = array[i];
}
```

But then I'm not sure where to go next.

I read something on SO about malloc, but even after seeing the code, I'm not sure how to use it.

Comment: You simply cannot resize an array.

Comment: how would I make sure that when I loop through the array to not let it reach the "4th" index then?

Comment: Maintain a separate variable with the number of meaningful entries in the array. Use that rather than the array's size in your loops. When you remove an element, decrease this count.

Comment: Better yet, find and use the appropriate data structure for your problem (not an array). From just the description you've provided here, you are probably looking for a stack or a queue.

Comment: Note that if you want this to be more selfcontained, you could (should?) set up a struct which bundles the array -- or a pointer to a malloc'd memory block -- and the count together.

Comment: Rather than shifting all values in the array and using something to track the "current last index"; wouldn't it make more sense to track the "current first index" to avoid shifting all the values?

Comment: keslam, so you are saying I should set i = size variable?....What about my loop though, does it look appropriate in terms of how to shift elements to the left?...Somehow, I'm thinking there could be an index out of range error but not sure why

Comment: @TokugawaIeysu No, your algorithm is wrong. Just think about it and/or draw it on paper. If you are going from the end of the array, then you are overwriting every element with the last element. You have to go from 0 to the size of the array. Also, the `sizeof` operator doesn't do what you think it does. Google `sizeof` before using it.

Comment: @H2CO3, yes you are right, I'm an idiot! So assuming I set a size variable to indicate how many elements are in the array and decrement when one is removed, do I start i = 0 while i < size, and then set array[i= array[i+1]?

Comment: @TokugawaIeysu Yes, that's what you have to do.

Comment: @H2CO3 since arrays cannot be resized since its not decided at runtime  as mentioned by sortfiend, what to do with the value 5 in the last index 4?...Is it just there wasting memory space?

Comment: @TokugawaIeysu Yeah, sort of. It doesn't quite "waste" memory, though. You shouldn't really be worrying about one `int`. (Especially not when your array size is bounded, as in this example.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C does not allow you to do this at all because the size of the array is not decided at runtime.

The memory for an array is allocated either statically or automatically, depending on some specifics of your program. Statically and automatically allocated memory is not "affected" by runtime variables or changes, which you can see in C's inability to do something like: `int breaks[some_runtime_variable]`.

If you'd like to read more about memory allocation in C, and some ways of how to solve this problem using dynamic memory allocation, see my answer on Quora here: http://qr.ae/htfYE

To be a bit more specific to this question, [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_%28abstract_data_type%29#Array)'s a toy implementation of a [stack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_%28abstract_data_type%29) in C.

As you can see from the implementations of push and pop, the stack explicitly keeps track of its current size as a separate field of the struct, which allows constant time LIFO pushes and pops.

The stack doesn't technically "shrink" when you pop from it, but if you treat the stack implementation like a black box it may as well shrink when you pop and grow when you push.

Answer (score 0):

You can use realloc() function refer http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_dynamic_memory_allocation